# python: read line from file and store in list

Tags: python-2.7

I want to read and store each column from file to each list. For example, the file looks like as follows:

data.txt:

1234 asdf

2341 asda

1231 asdf

... ...

And, I want to store like: `list_1=[1234, 2341, 1231, ...]`, `list_2=[asdf, asda, asdf, ...]`. I write a code as follows:

```
def parse():
    list_1 = []
    list_2 = []
    with open('data.txt', 'rb') as f:
        for line in f:
            a = line.strip().split()
            list_1 = a[0]
            list_2 = a[1]
```

When I just `print a[0]`, `print a[1]`, the code works very well. However, when I write like the above code, there appears

> IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: Check the length of "a" before putting the items in the list. If you have a header which don't have two columns you will face that error.

Comment: Thank! It works after checking the length of "a" before appending them to lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you probably meant to call `append` on the lists, as in `list_1.append(a[0])` and the corresponding change for `list_2`. Also, you probably want to append `float(a[0])` if `a[0]` should later be treated as a number.

The `IndexError` probably comes from an empty line in the input (possibly the last line). To resolve it, either check `len(a)` before accessing its elements, or make sure the code is only given clean input.

Answer (score 0):

Skip empty lines and append to your lists:

```
list_1 = []
list_2 = []
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        a, b = line.split()
        list_1.append(int(a))
        list_2.append(b)
```